# IntelliJ IDEA app unable to connect to Firebase

Tags: java, firebase, intellij-idea, android-emulator

While testing my android java app built using IntelliJ Idea 2022.2.2, The app cannot move past the loading screen. Initially, I thought this was a problem with the emulator's internet, however, I was able to use Google Chrome on the emulator without any issue.

I have not changed any code relating to the Login Screen, and cannot understand why the app is behaving this way, even though I have turned of my VPN, cold booted my emulator, deleted and reinstalled the emulator, and restarted my computer multiple times.

Is this a problem with my app, IDE, or emulator? To sign into my app, my back-end provider is Google Firebase, I have attached a photo below of the window that the Login screen crashes on after I login, The emulator API level is 24. I would greatly appreciate if someone could provide some assistance into this error, thanks :)

[image: The login screen cannot move past this window]

The login screen is unable to move past the window above, and after 2 minutes, firebase gives this message.

[image]

This is my Logcat

```
2022-09-23 11:54:17.141 8073-8073/com.example.exampros W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.exampros-1/lib/x86
2022-09-23 11:54:17.105 8073-8073/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2022-09-23 11:54:17.105 8073-8073/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2022-09-23 11:54:17.171 8073-8073/com.example.exampros I/FirebaseApp: Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
2022-09-23 11:54:17.214 8073-8073/com.example.exampros I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
2022-09-23 11:54:17.219 8073-8088/com.example.exampros W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date for com.example.exampros.  Requires 12451000 but found 11743470
2022-09-23 11:54:17.240 8073-8092/com.example.exampros I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to fallback implementation
2022-09-23 11:54:17.253 8073-8073/com.example.exampros W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
2022-09-23 11:54:17.321 8073-8073/com.example.exampros D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa73bc980, tid 8073
2022-09-23 11:54:17.432 8073-8094/com.example.exampros D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa73bcd80, tid 8094
2022-09-23 11:54:17.434 8073-8094/com.example.exampros I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2022-09-23 11:54:17.434 8073-8094/com.example.exampros D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2022-09-23 11:54:17.435 8073-8094/com.example.exampros W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2022-09-23 11:54:17.435 8073-8094/com.example.exampros D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
2022-09-23 11:54:17.450 8073-8094/com.example.exampros D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xb4b054e0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2022-09-23 11:54:17.484 8073-8094/com.example.exampros D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb4b054e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb4b033c0)
2022-09-23 11:54:17.500 8073-8094/com.example.exampros D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb4b054e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb4b033c0)
2022-09-23 11:54:23.392 8073-8107/com.example.exampros W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date for com.example.exampros.  Requires 11925000 but found 11743470
2022-09-23 11:54:23.400 8073-8107/com.example.exampros E/GooglePlayServicesUtil: GooglePlayServices not available due to error 2
2022-09-23 11:54:23.401 8073-8107/com.example.exampros W/Firestore: (24.0.0) [GrpcCallProvider]: Failed to update ssl context: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException: Google Play Services not available
2022-09-23 11:54:23.476 8073-8107/com.example.exampros D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2022-09-23 11:54:23.528 8073-8107/com.example.exampros W/art: Before Android 4.1, method double java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.internalNextDouble(double, double) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in java.util.Random
2022-09-23 11:54:23.529 8073-8107/com.example.exampros W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.internalNextInt(int, int) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in java.util.Random
2022-09-23 11:54:23.529 8073-8107/com.example.exampros W/art: Before Android 4.1, method long java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.internalNextLong(long, long) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in java.util.Random
2022-09-23 11:54:33.576 8073-8106/com.example.exampros W/Firestore: (24.0.0) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds
    
    This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
2022-09-23 11:54:33.580 8073-8073/com.example.exampros D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    
    
    --------- beginning of crash
2022-09-23 11:54:33.580 8073-8073/com.example.exampros E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.exampros, PID: 8073
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Long com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.getLong(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.exampros.DbQuery$6.onSuccess(DbQuery.java:107)
        at com.example.exampros.DbQuery$6.onSuccess(DbQuery.java:94)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzm.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
2022-09-23 11:54:38.696 8073-8108/com.example.exampros E/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler: callback not found for RELEASED message
2022-09-23 11:54:38.703 8073-8106/com.example.exampros W/Firestore: (24.0.0) [WatchStream]: (d33f4e5) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Channel shutdownNow invoked, cause=null}.
2022-09-23 11:54:38.707 8073-8118/com.example.exampros W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date for com.example.exampros.  Requires 11925000 but found 11743470
2022-09-23 11:54:38.709 8073-8118/com.example.exampros E/GooglePlayServicesUtil: GooglePlayServices not available due to error 2
2022-09-23 11:54:38.709 8073-8118/com.example.exampros W/Firestore: (24.0.0) [GrpcCallProvider]: Failed to update ssl context: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException: Google Play Services not available
2022-09-23 11:54:53.771 8073-8108/com.example.exampros E/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler: callback not found for RELEASED message
2022-09-23 11:54:53.777 8073-8131/com.example.exampros W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date for com.example.exampros.  Requires 11925000 but found 11743470
2022-09-23 11:54:53.778 8073-8131/com.example.exampros E/GooglePlayServicesUtil: GooglePlayServices not available due to error 2
2022-09-23 11:54:53.779 8073-8131/com.example.exampros W/Firestore: (24.0.0) [GrpcCallProvider]: Failed to update ssl context: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException: Google Play Services not available
```

Comment: Check if there are any related warnings/exceptions in [Logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat).

Comment: I have added the Logcat Information, can you please see it and suggest what can be done to resolve this issue? Thanks:)

Comment: Looks like it might be a problem with your code. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62421292/12844632 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Ok, thank you for the help, I am checking them out

Comment: I figured out the solution, I changed my emulator from Pixel_2_API_24 to Nexus_5X_API_32